# Python Pandas Dataframe convert julian day column to date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, julian-date

I have a column full of julian days. I want to convert them to date format.

```
df1.shape()
(638765, 94)

df1['DAY'] = 
0         2022216 # Format = year (2022),day of the year (216)
1         2022216
2         2022216
3         2022216
4         2022216

from datetime import datetime
```

Solution-1:

```
%timeit df1['Date'] = df1['DAY'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime('%d'%x,'%Y%j').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
11.9 s ± 50.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
0        2022-08-04
1        2022-08-04
2        2022-08-04
3        2022-08-04
4        2022-08-04
```

Solution-2:

```
%timeit df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DAY'], format='%Y%j')

20.3 ms ± 243 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
0        2022-08-04
1        2022-08-04
2        2022-08-04
3        2022-08-04
4        2022-08-04
```

I liked the above solution-2 very much, since it takes less than a second and other one takes around 11 s. My question: is this default behavior for the `to_datetime` to convert a given julian day to the date format ('%Y-%m-%d') even though I did not specify it?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - you *did* specify `format='%Y%j'`, no? Also, the difference in execution speed should not come as a surprise; the pandas built-in `to_datetime`  is optimized to work with pandas while the `apply` is essentially an iteration (in Python - slow in most cases!) that calls another library (vanilla Python datetime) *and* requires a conversion from Python's datetime to pandas datetime data type. Essentially if you want Python scripts to be fast, you do **not** want to do the heavy-lifting in Python.

Comment: @FObersteiner I mean, I did not specify the output format no where in the code, that is `'%Y-%m-%d'`. Nowhere I mentioned it. Automatically did it, which is also I wanted.

Comment: I see, so since the result in both cases (the apply and to_datetime) is a column of data type datetime, you can only change the *format* (how it's being displayed) if you convert to string, e.g. `.dt.strftime("%b %d %Y")`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a coincidence.

In your 1st solution, you [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to the `"%Y-%m-%d"` format and it happened that the function [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) (that you use in your 2nd solution) returns a `DatetimeIndex` with this same format. And that's because [`"%Y-%m-%d"` is the default format of the latter](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/89b37c91ea33f39f522e99e9918ff44fc9648408/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1826).

Under the hood, the conversion of your julian days is handled (at the very end of the processing) by [`_box_as_indexlike`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e86ed377639948c64c429059127bcf5b359ab6be/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L266C5-L266C22) and this one converts a numpy array that holds the parsed datetimes to a `DatetimeIndex` :

```
#1 the input :
array([2022216, 2022216, 2022216, 2022216, 2022216], dtype=object)

#2 `array_stptime` gives :
array(['2022-08-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2022-08-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2022-08-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2022-08-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2022-08-04T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

#3 `_box_as_indexlike` gives :
DatetimeIndex(['2022-08-04', '2022-08-04', '2022-08-04', '2022-08-04',
               '2022-08-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: **NB**: Your 1st and 2nd solutions yield two different dtypes : `object/strings` and `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: ok OP is even more convoluted than I thought; didn't scroll to the right to see the `strftime` ^^